# Console Output - Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I run a script in jenkins the following error is displayed:

```
Started by user *********
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.<init>(CpsScript.java:69)
    at WorkflowScript.<init>(WorkflowScript)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:434)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I can't figure out which plugin is missing or which version is incorrect.

```
Java version 2.176.1

Ant Plugin  1.9 <br>
Apache HttpComponents Client 4.x API Plugin 4.5.5-3.0   <br>
Authentication Tokens API Plugin    1.3 <br>
Backup plugin   1.6.1   <br>
bouncycastle API Plugin 2.17    <br>
Branch API Plugin   2.5.2   <br>
Build Monitor View  1.12    <br>
Build Timeout   1.19    <br>
buildgraph-view 1.8 <br>
built-on-column 1.1 <br>
Command Agent Launcher Plugin   1.3 <br>
Conditional BuildStep   1.3.6   <br>
Config File Provider Plugin 3.6.2   <br>
Copy data to workspace plugin   1.0 <br>
Credentials Binding Plugin  1.19    <br>
Credentials Plugin  2.2.0   <br>
Cucumber reports    4.8.0   <br>
Cucumber Trend Reports  1.3 <br>
Display URL API 2.3.1   <br>
Docker Commons Plugin   1.15    <br>
Docker Pipeline 1.18    <br>
Durable Task Plugin 1.29    <br>
Email Extension Plugin  2.66    <br>
EnvInject API Plugin    1.5 <br>
Environment Injector Plugin 2.1.6   <br>
External Monitor Job Type Plugin    1.7 <br>
File System SCM Plugin  2.1 <br>
Folders Plugin  6.9 <br>
Git client plugin   2.8.0   <br>
Git plugin  3.10.1  <br>
GIT server Plugin   1.7 <br>
GitHub API Plugin   1.95    <br>
GitHub Authentication plugin    0.32    <br>
GitHub Branch Source Plugin 2.5.3   <br>
GitHub Organization Folder Plugin   1.6 <br>
GitHub plugin   1.29.4  <br>
Gitlab Authentication plugin    1.4 <br>
GitLab Plugin   1.5.12  <br>
Gradle Plugin   1.33    <br>
Green Balls 1.15    <br>
Groovy  2.2 <br>
HP Operations Orchestration Automation Execution Plugin 2.1.1   <br>
Icon Shim Plugin    2.0.3   <br>
Jackson 2 API Plugin    2.9.9   <br>
Javadoc Plugin  1.5 <br>
JavaScript GUI Lib: ACE Editor bundle plugin    1.1 <br>
JavaScript GUI Lib: Handlebars bundle plugin    1.1.1   <br>
JavaScript GUI Lib: jQuery bundles (jQuery and jQuery UI) plugin    1.2.1   <br>
JavaScript GUI Lib: Moment.js bundle plugin 1.1.1   <br>
JavaScript GUI Lib: Twitter Bootstrap bundle plugin 1.3.2   <br>
JDK Tool Plugin 1.2 <br>
jQuery plugin   1.12.4-0    <br>
jQuery UI plugin    1.0.2   <br>
JSch dependency plugin  0.1.55  <br>
JUnit Plugin    1.28    <br>
LDAP Plugin 1.20    <br>
Lockable Resources plugin   2.5 <br>
Mailer Plugin   1.23    <br>
MapDB API Plugin    1.0.9.0 <br>
Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin    2.4.2   <br>
Matrix Project Plugin   1.14    <br>
Maven Integration plugin    3.3 <br>
Micro Focus Application Automation Tools    5.8 <br>
Multijob plugin 1.32    <br>
OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin   1.5 <br>
PAM Authentication plugin   1.5.1   <br>
Parameterized Scheduler 0.6.3   <br>
Parameterized Trigger plugin    2.35.2  <br>
Periodic Backup 1.5 <br>
Pipeline    2.6 <br>
Pipeline Aggregator 1.8 <br>
Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin  1.10    <br>
Pipeline: API   2.35    <br>
Pipeline: Basic Steps   2.18    <br>
Pipeline: Build Step    2.9 <br>
Pipeline: Declarative   1.3.9   <br>
Pipeline: Declarative Agent API 1.1.1   <br>
Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API  1.3.9   <br>
Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries   1.0 <br>
Pipeline: Groovy    2.70    <br>
Pipeline: Input Step    2.10    <br>
Pipeline: Job   2.33    <br>
Pipeline: Milestone Step    1.3.1   <br>
Pipeline: Model API 1.3.9   <br>
Pipeline: Multibranch   2.21    <br>
Pipeline: Multibranch with defaults 1.1 <br>
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes   2.31    <br>
Pipeline: REST API Plugin   2.11    <br>
Pipeline: SCM Step  2.9 <br>
Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries   2.13    <br>
Pipeline: Stage Step    2.3 <br>
Pipeline: Stage Tags Metadata   1.3.9   <br>
Pipeline: Stage View Plugin 2.11    <br>
Pipeline: Step API  2.20    <br>
Pipeline: Supporting APIs   3.3 <br>
Plain Credentials Plugin    1.5 <br>
PowerShell plugin   1.3 <br>
promoted builds plugin  3.3 <br>
Resource Disposer Plugin    0.12    <br>
Role-based Authorization Strategy   2.13    <br>
Run Condition Plugin    1.2 <br>
Safe Restart Plugin 0.3 <br>
SCM API Plugin  2.6.3   <br>
Script Security Plugin  1.61    <br>
Shared Workspace    1.0.2   <br>
SSH Agent Plugin    1.17    <br>
SSH Credentials Plugin  1.17.1  <br>
SSH plugin  2.6.1   <br>
SSH Slaves plugin   1.30.0  <br>
Structs Plugin  1.19    <br>
Subversion Plug-in  2.12.2  <br>
SVN 1.3 Compatibility Plugin    1.2 <br>
SVN 1.4 Compatibility Plugin    1.1 <br>
Timestamper 1.10    <br>
Token Macro Plugin  2.8 <br>
WMI Windows Agents Plugin   1.4 <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found is that it's hard to diagnose and the following steps might help you recover

1. Manually remove the workflow packages from JENKINS_HOME/plugins
2. Upgrading all plugins.
3. Restarting jenkins.
4. Download the workflow plugins, and set to install on restart.
5. Then it was working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to specify "node" you are running your pipeline stage on :

```
node('my_slave') {
    stage('my_stage') {
        // do fancy code
    }
}
```

Regards